# App on Dev iPhone Not Starting on Certain Network Operators

Tags: iphone, networking

We develop iPhone apps in Europe and sometimes we demo them in the USA using our dev iPhones that we bring with us. Our apps connect to our services (server-side apps) to pull data to operate. We recently noticed something strange. Depending on the carrier that we select as network operator our app may not work. It just doesn't start as if it cannot negotiate the network connection. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Data Roaming switched off in Settings? If so, that'll halt your data if you're roaming abroad.

Also, different carriers might not allow data from roaming phones. For instance, in the UK O2 has 'preferred' carriers in different countries, and you only get the full set of roaming features if you connect to those carriers. You *can* connect to the others, but you won't get everything and calls (etc) will be more expensive.

This isn't a coding problem at all, or even a problem with the iPhone. It's purely a network issue.

Comment: Yes, the roaming is on as it works as soon as we switch network operator. Thanks for the explanation. I just wanted to know if we were missing something obvious or not.